# Button's action causes "invalid selector" crash -- why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, target-action

This code results in an "invalid selector" error when the button I create is pressed. Where is the `test` function fetched from?

Main.m

```
mainScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
[self.view addSubview:mainScreen];

TaskButtons *tB = [[TaskButtons alloc] init];
[mainScreen addSubview:[tB TaskStart]];
```

TaskButtons.m

```
- (UIButton*)TaskStart {
   CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(500, 206, 400, 35);
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   button.frame = buttonFrame;
   [button setTitle:@"Task Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
   [button setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(test) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   return button;
 }

- (void)test{
   NSLog(@"test line");
}
```

It seems that the `test` function isn't being called. Doesn't setting the button's `target` to `self` here mean it should look in the `TaskButtons` class for the function called `test`?

Comment: Please include the text of the invalid selector message. This will tell you which object the action message is really being sent to.

Comment: I found out it is ARC trying to release my instantiated object too soon before the selector can be called. If I import TaskButtons.m into Main.h and TaskButtons *tB; in the interface. Then retain it in a property by @property (nonatomic, retain) TaskButtons *tB; I can keep the instantiated class around long enough to call the selector without ARC releasing my class too soon.

Comment: `test` is a method, not a function.

Comment: This may be secondary, but UIControl selectors are in the form `@selector(method:)`, where the signature would look like `-(void)method:(id)sender`. Omitting the argument may result in unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is ARC is releasing the instantiated object too soon. So to solve this I would need to retain it longer.

Main.h

```
#import "TaskButtons.m"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
     TaskButtons *tB;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TaskButtons *tB;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)test:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"test line");
}
```

Syntax problem :) In your code replace these lines.